# Windows 10 create several gigabytes of crashdump files

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 (64 bit, Fall Creators Update) creates several gigabytes of crashdump files to c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\CrashDumps folder.

I have already set to create small memory files (256KB).

The dump files related to various programs (based on their name).

What can I do?

Sample dump file summary (by Visual Studio):

[image]

Comment: this means a lot of programs crashed. look in eventlog for more details about the crashes

Comment: cd c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\CrashDumps, then erase *.* /y

Comment: I never see any program crash. Eg. now I started Photoshop > open psd > dump file created. But I can use Photoshop without any problem (I noticed slower file opening).

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Of course I can delete those files but I don't want to do this again and again...

Comment: Can you maybe provide a couple of dump files?  The fact that multiple applications are crashing suggests there is a common problem.

Comment: “What can I do?” - You can be more specific.  **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.**

Comment: @Ramhound I can't be more specific. Dump files are created >> I want to disable large dump file creation. That is all.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, stop responding for a while but after that everything is fine.

Comment: @HelpingHand I added a dump summary. Is it enough? Dump files are several gigabytes.

Comment: Not really, are you saying each dump file is several gig?  I'd only be interested to see one or 2.

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes, eg. the last dump file is 2.5 GB.

Comment: OK, what about if you: 1. Create a directory `C:\dumps` 2. Download Procdump (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) and save that to `C:\dumps`. 3. In an admin prompt run: `C:\dumps\procdump.exe -mp -i C:\dumps`. How big are the dumps then?

Comment: “The dump files related to various programs (based on their name).” If you cannot be more specific that’s a problem

Comment: Maybe try just:
`C:\dumps\procdump.exe -i C:\dumps` that should reduce the size.

Comment: @kovak : Did `C:\dumps\procdump.exe -i C:\dumps` help to reduce the size of the dumps being create when processes encounter an exception leading to a crash?  If so, presumably you have a few now in C:\dumps\.  Feel free to share a couple so we can work out the root cause.

Comment: the message in the picture shows you got a crash. [disable CFG force](https://superuser.com/a/1275445/174557) and look if the apps no longer crash/hang