# What are the security risks of disabling Control Flow Guard for the Desktop Window Manager service in Windows 10

Tags: windows, security

The exploit protection feature Control Flow Guard was enabled as the default on my Windows 10 system and I made an exception for the Desktop Window Manager service (`C:\WINDOWS\System32\dwm.exe`) so that my Multitasking View would be more responsive.

I learned about this performance enhancement from this question: [Windows 10 - windows open slow, GUI draw slows down with heavy multitasking - but why?](https://superuser.com/questions/1273959/windows-10-windows-open-slow-gui-draw-slows-down-with-heavy-multitasking-bu)

Pressing Win+Tab reveals the Multitasking View much faster for me now but I'm wondering what exploit protection I'm losing through this CFG exception.

Comment: Read here....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/control-flow-guard

Comment: Thanks @Moab, This explains a lot about CFG and I'm wondering how exposed `dwm.exe` is in the first place for receiving bad memory or writing bad memory.